# How to get some information about a .NET project

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I work at a company that developed their own software, and I want to access the code or just get the most info on how it works, i think it is a dotnet project because I saw the following files in the application folder :

> bunch of .dll files ; .pdb ; .config

And the `.exe` for the app and a bin folder that has similar files plus a `.ini`.

I have visual studio Professional 2022, asking to have access to source code takes too much time because I work in the finance department, but I am a developer.

Just want to see what I can find by myself and your help of course.

Unfortunately i haven't worked with visual studio for `.net` so am kind of lost.

Comment: Assuming it is a .NET Framework application you could always try decompiling the DLLs! with something like ILSpy.

Comment: That's good to know, but unfortunately I am not allowed install software that is not offered by the company, so there is no way to do it with only VS ?

Comment: As a developer,  you need to have  access to such tools. If the company refuses to let you do your job, it's probably time to look for a new one, as you will keep running into limitations.

Comment: Here, you could use ildasm, though. It's less comfortable than ilspy, but part of the .NET SDK.